# Presence of a source in all available AS400 libraries

Tags: ibm-midrange

How to check the presence of a source in all the available AS400 libraries. I want to know in which libraries program pgmxxxx is available. Is there any possible way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While querying SYSTABLES can get you a list of all source files on the system, you need to query SYSPARTITIONDISK to get a list of source members.

This is what it would look like:

```
select table_schema as library,
       table_name as file,
       table_partition as member 
from qsys2.syspartitiondisk
where table_partition = '<your source member name>'
```

You can speed this up significantly by restricting the file name or library using `table_name` or `table_schema` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

All tables of type source on iseries aka as400 aka poweri.

```
SELECT * FROM QSYS2/SYSTABLES WHERE FILE_TYPE = 'S'
```